# Prounciation of Ypres... in all six languages?

Tags: pronunciation

I know how to pronounce Ypres in both French and English, but what about the pronounciations in Flemish, Belgian, Dutch and German? How is it pronounced all six ways?

Comment: What, out of curiosity, is Belgian?

Comment: @user6726 That is the language Belgians speak when they are drinking Belgian beer.